# Definite integral with hyperbolic cosine and circumference segment

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I've been struggling with this definite integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}{b+\cosh x} dx,$$
with
$$ a>0,\\ b>1.$$

**Mathematica won't solve it**

Any idea on how to solve this kind of integral?

Comment: Hi & welcome to MSE. Is there any particular reason that you believe the solution to this integral can be expressed in closed form?

Comment: I'm no expert by any means, but I've personally never seen an integral of this form having a closed form. The core methods that jump out at me at trigonometric and the hyperbolic half tangent substitutions. As a possible start I would use the maclaurin series for the numerator and then use the half tangent substitution to (hopefully) evaluate each term of the series. From there you may be able to use some know identities to form a closed form. I can post this up in detail if you would like. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Even $b=0$ will probably make the problem impossible to solve and I guess that numeical integration could be the only way.

For an *approximate* result, we could expand the integrand as a Taylor series built at $x=0$ to get
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}{b+\cosh (x)}=\frac{1}{b+1}-\frac{x^2 \left(a^2+b+1\right)}{2 \left(a^2 (b+1)^2\right)}-\frac{x^4
   \left(a^4 (b-5)-6 a^2 (b+1)+3 (b+1)^2\right)}{24 \left(a^4
   (b+1)^3\right)}+\frac{x^6 \left(a^6 (-((b-28) b+61))+15 a^4 (b-5) (b+1)+45 a^2
   (b+1)^2-45 (b+1)^3\right)}{720 a^6 (b+1)^4}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ and integrate termwise.

For the definite integral this would lead to
$$\int_0^a\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}{b+\cosh (x)}=-\frac{a \left(a^6 \left(b^2-28 b+61\right)+27 a^4 \left(b^2-4 b-5\right)+543 a^2
   (b+1)^2-4029 (b+1)^3\right)}{5040 (b+1)^4}+\cdots$$ which could be acceptable for small values of $a$ as shown below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a   & b & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 1 & 0.099507 & 0.097793 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 2 & 0.066431 & 0.065280 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 3 & 0.049858 & 0.048992 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 4 & 0.039903 & 0.039209 \\
             &   &           &           \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 1 & 0.132247 & 0.129999 \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 2 & 0.088382 & 0.086864 \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 3 & 0.066368 & 0.065223 \\
 \frac{1}{3} & 4 & 0.053134 & 0.052215 \\
             &   &           &           \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0.196565 & 0.193344 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 2 & 0.131756 & 0.129550 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 3 & 0.099089 & 0.097412 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 4 & 0.079403 & 0.078050 \\
     &   &           &           \\
 1           & 1 & 0.375025 & 0.370035 \\
 1 & 2 & 0.255071 & 0.251336 \\
 1 & 3 & 0.193296 & 0.190346 \\
 1 & 4 & 0.155625 & 0.153190
\end{array}
\right)$$